# How to redirect page with jquery delay 3000 sec after delete data in aspnet core mvc

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have a delete method in asp.net core. When user delete data it return redirect to action. I want to when user delete data delete success message shown and after 3 seconds redirect another page

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Student/Delete/{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {

            var student = _context.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Students.Remove(student);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs changes in two locations:

1. On the server

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("Student/Delete/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var student = _context.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == id);

    if (student == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    _context.Students.Remove(student);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```

2. On the client (JavaScript/jQuery)

```
function delete(id) {

    $.post('/Student/Delete/' + id).done(function(result) {
        // show your message in some HTML tag with id="message"
        $('#message').text('Deleted successfully!');

        // wait for 3 seconds before redirecting
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = '/Students'; // or wherever to
        }, 3000);
    }).fail(function(err) {
        const msg = 'An error occured';
        console.error(msg, err);
        $('#message').text(msg);
    });

}
```